# cs50 pset3, frequency function not working

Tags: c, cs50

I am completely new to C language and this course is the first time I am trying C.

The question asks to calculate and return the frequency of the notes. Frequency is calculated based on the relative position of a note from A4. 
[Here](https://docs.cs50.net/2018/x/psets/3/music/music.html) is the complete question.

After using the debugger I found that the value of freq variable is not updating inside the switch statement and I don't know why.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int frequency(string note)
{


    char n = note[0]; //first character is a note 'A, B..'
    float freq = 0.0;

    //second character can be an accidental or an octave
    if (note[1] == '#' || note[1] == 'b')
    {
        int octave = note[2] - '0';
        freq = 440 * powf(2, octave - 4); //frequency of note 'A' taken as base

        switch (n) // changing frequency depending upon the relative position of note from A
        {
            case 'C':
                freq = freq / powf(2, 9/12); //C is 9 semitones away from A
                break;

            case 'D':
                freq = freq / powf(2, 7/12);
                break;

            case 'E':
                freq = freq / powf(2, 5/12);
                break;

            case 'F':
                freq = freq / powf(2, 4/12);
                break;

            case 'G':
                freq = freq / powf(2, 2/12);
                break;

            case 'B':
                freq = freq * powf(2, 4/12);
                break;
        }

        //changing frequency depending upon # of b
        if (note[1] == '#')
        {
            freq = round(freq * powf(2, 1/12));
        }
        else
        {
            freq =  round(freq / powf(2, 1/12));
        }

    }
    else
    {
        int octave = note[1] - '0';
        freq = 440 * powf(2, octave - 4);//frequency of note A taken as base

        switch (n) // changing frequency depending upon the relative position of note from A
        {
            case 'C':
                freq  = round(freq / powf(2, 9/12));
                break;

            case 'D':
                freq  = round(freq / powf(2, 7/12));
                break;

            case 'E':
                freq  = round(freq / powf(2, 5/12));
                break;

            case 'F':
                freq  = round(freq / powf(2, 4/12));
                break;

            case 'G':
                freq  = round(freq / powf(2, 2/12));
                break;

            case 'A':
                freq  = round(freq);
                break;

            case 'B':
                freq  = round(freq * powf(2, 4/12));
                break;
        }
    }

    return freq;

}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%i\n", frequency("C5"));
    printf("%i\n", frequency("C#5"));

}
```

OUTPUT of above code

```
880
880
```

expected output

```
523
554
```

880 is the frequency of A5.

Comment: Looks like the switch statement is only reached when the note is a sharp or a flat.

Comment: The only way that `freq` would not be updated inside the `switch` statement would be if your value of `n` didn't match any of the cases. More detailed debugging should prove that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
powf(2, 9/12)
```

will give the result 1 because `9/12` is calculated using integers.

That is: `powf(2, 9/12)` is the same as `powf(2, 0)`

Try

```
powf(2, 9.0/12)
```

instead to force the calculation of 9 divided by 12 to be done using floating point.